# Delete table row when clicked on table data column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I want to delete a table row when i click on delete.
For this i have placed a `<a>` in the table row. 
So `onclick` of that the row needs to be deleted.

I have it working for one set of rows but not for another set.

DeleteRow function:

```
function DeleteRow(e) {
            $(e).closest(".CollectionItem").remove()
        }
```

Works for:

```
<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Items</div>
<div class="collapsible-body" style="margin:15px">
    <div id="ItemArea">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var Item in Model.Items)
            {
                <div class="card CollectionItem">
                    <div class="row" style="margin:15px">
                        <div class="col s10">
                            <input placeholder="Item" id="" name="" type="text" class="validate ItemInput" value="@Item">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s2" style="padding-top:10px">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn light-blue darken-3 deleteRow valign" id="DeleteItem" onclick="DeleteRow(this)">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn light-blue darken-3" id="AddItem" style="margin:10px">Add Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work for:

```
<table id="BuildDefinitionTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Team Project</th>
            <th>Build Definition</th>
            <th>Drop Build</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var BuildDefinition in Model.BuildDefinitions)
            {
                <tr class="CollectionItem">
                    <td><input type='text' readonly value="@BuildDefinition.TeamProject" style="border-bottom:none"/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' readonly value="@BuildDefinition.Name" style="border-bottom:none"/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' readonly value="@BuildDefinition.IsDropBuild.ToString()" style='border-bottom:none'/></td>
                    <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn light-blue darken-3 deleteRow valign" id="DeleteItem" onclick="DeleteRow(this)">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone see why this is, I cant get the delete button to even link to another page by using href.

Comment: $(e).parent().parent().remove(); try it this way https://jsfiddle.net/8wqvg8hp/1/ , any way your code also works

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8wqvg8hp/. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Hmmm Ok, thanks Hudhaifa Yoosuf and @Rory Crossan good to know i wasn't going insane